# Chrome WebKitBlobBuilder doesn't append data

Tags: javascript, ajax, webkit, binary, xmlhttprequest

I'm implementing some file upload feature through ajax request. I'd like to be able to send multiple files in one ajax call, so i decided to use FormData.

I tried to append my binary data string directly to the FormData (and it works), but the Content-Disposition doesn't have a filename attribute:
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file1"

w3c says that i need to append a blob object to the formdata to have that attribute (or to be able to set it with the 3rd attribute of FormData.append())

I wrote the following code:

```
function uploadAsBinary() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var fd = new FormData();

    window.BlobBuilder = window.BlobBuilder || window.WebKitBlobBuilder || window.MozBlobBuilder;
    var bb = new window.BlobBuilder();
    bb.append("this is my binary content");
    var blob = bb.getBlob("text/plain"); 

    fd.append("file1", blob, "file1");

    xhr.open("POST", "/mb/0/", false);
    xhr.send(fd);
}
```

It works perfectly fine with firefox, but with google chrome (v16 and v17), the request payload is a formdata without content in it:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryVkgESMAGtmPMlPZ7
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file1"; filename="file1"
Content-Type: text/plain


------WebKitFormBoundaryVkgESMAGtmPMlPZ7--
```

I've also tried to fill the blob through an ArrayBuffer, same result. 
I've been surfing the web for 2 days now, i've found no answer. I've found an open issue on android (http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=22441) but it seems quite dead.

Is this a real chrome issue ? Does someone have a clue about this, or should i open an issue on chromium tracker ?

Thx for your help !

Comment: FYI: i've opened an issue to chromium: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=119254

Comment: It seems this is still an issue, are there any workarounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone looking for a solution here, the problem is the switch to Blob() rather than BlobBuilder() as [explained here](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/06/Don-t-Build-Blobs-Construct-Them)

**BlobBuilder():**

```
window.BlobBuilder = window.BlobBuilder || window.WebKitBlobBuilder ||
                 window.MozBlobBuilder || window.MSBlobBuilder;
window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

var bb = new BlobBuilder();
bb.append('body { color: red; }');
var blob = bb.getBlob('text/css');

var link = document.createElement('link');
link.rel = 'stylesheet';
link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

document.body.appendChild(link);
```

**Blob():**

```
window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

var blob = new Blob(['body { color: red; }'], {type: 'text/css'});

var link = document.createElement('link');
link.rel = 'stylesheet';
link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
document.body.appendChild(link);
```

Comment: As noted here https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=119254#c7, switching from BlobBuilder.getBlob() to new Blob() does not resolve this issue on Google Chrome.

Comment: I didn't mean it as a personal blow. I upvote answers I find useful at the time that I encounter them and downvote answers I find unhelpful at the time I encounter them. That said, in spite of the issue I found, switching to Blob does appear to work, though it doesn't get rid of the symptom described in the post.

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr** Chrome Development Tools appears to clip file data from the data payload preview. Switching from `BlobBuilder` to `Blob` resolves the issue, but the preview of the payload still won't show file data; it will look the same as what you posted (apparently empty).

The symptom you describe is deceptive. I ran into a similar issue (turned out it was caused by incorrect overload of `Content-Type`, but I digress).

When my issue was resolved, I noticed that the Chrome Development Tools was showing plain key/value data, but not file data. When uploading a large file, I would get something like this:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryHyzYwSEV4FAfvi02
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="uploadType"

media
------WebKitFormBoundaryHyzYwSEV4FAfvi02
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fileupload"; filename="blob"
Content-Type: application/zip


------WebKitFormBoundaryHyzYwSEV4FAfvi02--
```

Notice the "plain" data `uploadType=media` shows up, whereas the file data does not. The only way I confirmed that the file uploaded correctly (other than eventually getting a success code from the server) was by looking in the Network tab of Chrome Development Tools at the request headers **after the request was complete**. It showed `content-length: 1023235`, much larger than the supposedly empty file payload suggests.